# Using git commit ID as string in Visual Studio C project?

Tags: git, visual-studio

We have a Visual Studio 17 project written in ISO C, which is hosted in a git repro. How can we get the current git commit ID, or branch name, as string in the C code itself?

Comment: Create a pre build step that calculates commit ID and writes it to a header file that the project includes.

Comment: How do I do that in Visual Studio 17?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Visual+studio+pre+build